# $\iiint_{g(s)} (2x+y-2z)dx dy dz=\alpha\iiint_{s} z dx dy dz $..calculate $\alpha$

Tags: vector-analysis

Let $g:\mathbb{R}^{3}\to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ be defined by $g(x,y,z)=(3x+4z,2x-3z,x+3y)$ and let 
$s={\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^{3}:0\leq x\leq 1  ,0\leq y\leq 1 , 0\leq z\leq 1 }\}$.
if

$\iiint_{g(s)} (2x+y-2z)dx dy dz=\alpha\iiint_{s} z dx dy dz    $
then calculate value of $\alpha$??

what I did is: I substituted $x,y,z$ values from $g(x,y,z)$...in the equation ..but I dint get the correct anwer

Comment: If you show your working I'm sure someone can put you on the right track.

Comment: Duplicate [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2103023/evaluate-iiint-gs2xy-2zdxdydz-alpha-iiint-sz-dxdydz)