# A doubt in multivariable calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $g:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be defined by $g(x,y,z)=(3y+4z,2x-3z,x+3y)$ and let $S= \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : 0 \leq x \leq 1  ,0 \leq y \leq 1 , 0 \leq z\leq 1 \}.$

What is the image of the region $S$ under then mapping $g$?

**My attempt:**

Since $0 \leq y \leq 1 , 0 \leq z\leq 1$ and that the first coordinate of the mapping $g$ is $3y+4z,$ the first coordinate of the image of the region $S$ under $g$ will be from $0$ to $7.$
I got $0$ as lower limit because $min\{ 3y+4z : 0 \leq y \leq 1 , 0 \leq z\leq 1 \}=0$ and $max\{ 3y+4z : 0 \leq y \leq 1 , 0 \leq z\leq 1 \}=7.$
By doing this for second and third coordinate of the image of $S$ under $g,$ I got $g(S)$ as

$$g(S)=\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : 0 \leq x \leq 7  ,-3 \leq y \leq 2 , 0 \leq z\leq 4 \}.$$

Have I gone wrong somewhere?
I feel I have made a mistake because this was part of a bigger problem, and my answers are not matching.
Any ideas would be of great help.

P.S. The original question is: Find $\alpha$ such that
$$\iiint_{g(s)}(2x+y-2z)dxdydz=\alpha\iiint_S z dxdydz.$$

Comment: +1 to your posting, for nice presentation and nice work shown.  In my opinion, you **nailed it**.  If your answer is supposedly wrong, please :[1] give the exact wording of the problem that was assigned to you [2] give the (supposed) intended solution [3] provide any hints or explanation given of the intended solution.

Comment: The image of the unit cube S  by the linear map is a parallelepiped whose 8 vertices are the images of the corners of the cube.For example, one vertex is (7,-1,4)

Comment: $g$ is an invertible linear map therefore the image of the cube $S$ is the parallelepiped generated by the vectors $g(1,0,0)=(0,2,1)$, $g(0,1,0)=(3,0,3)$, $g(0,0,1)=(4,-3,0)$.

Comment: What you have computed is the min-max range of values of each resulting coordinate. But the ranges of each coordinate are not independent

Comment: You can't reach $(7,2,4)$, for example.

Comment: Actually this was the original question.

Let $g:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be defined by $g(x,y,z)=(3y+4z,2x-3z,x+3y)$ and let $S= \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : 0 \leq x \leq 1  ,0 \leq y \leq 1 , 0 \leq z\leq 1 \}.$
Find $\alpha$ if $$\iiint_{g(s)}(2x+y-2z)dxdydz=\alpha\iiint_S z dxdydz.$$
I evaluated the RHS to be $\frac{\alpha}{2}.$ I had problem with the LHS.
Please do let me know if there any other way to solve the LHS.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2103023/evaluate-iiint-gs2xy-2zdxdydz-alpha-iiint-sz-dxdydz

Comment: I understood where I had gone wrong. I got the expected answer. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your logic is that not every point in the image is reachable at the max and min for various coordinates.  For example,  you only get a $0$ in the $x$ coordinate of the image when both $y=z=0$,  so the only things in your image that hit 0 in coordinate 1 is $\{g(x,0,0)|x\in [0,1]\}=\{(0,2x,x)|x\in [0,1]\}$.   Thus ,  $(0,1,1)$ is not in the image of $g$, etc.

The easiest thing to do conceptually (ie without any calculus) is to calculate where each border edge goes to.   Since it is linear, you can skip this by just calculating the vertices as per @MathWonk 's comment

Comment: Here $g$ is an invertible linear map. So, we used the idea of corners of a parallelepiped being mapped to the corners of the parallelepiped. But is there a general way to do it? i.e., given any map $g: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3,$(not necessarily linear) is there a general way to find the image of a region $S,$ which is not neccesarily a cube.